# How vulnerable is a persistent, unencrypted Internet connection between 2 trusted networks?

Tags: networking, network-programming

Scenario: 2 network devices, each on separate private LANs. The LANs are connected by public Internet.

Device on network A is listening on a socket; network A firewall has NAT port forward setup for external access from network B's port range.

Device on network B makes outgoing connection to network A to connect to the listen socket.

Is there any difference in vulnerability of short-term connection made for a data transfer then dropped when complete (e.g. few seconds), and a persistent connection which employs a keep-alive mechanism and reconnects when dropped (hours, days, ..)?

The security of actually *making* the connection is not part of my question.

Comment: Why aren't you using a VPN and SSL?

Comment: I have suggested that as an alternative but have been asked to respond to the question of security of this mechanism as well.

Comment: If all they have is FUD, why respond in detail?  Just pitch the alternative and move on?

Comment: Because I'm not certain enough of my own knowledge of network infrastructure to be sure of my conclusion that it is just FUD.

Comment: @boycy: It doesn't matter.  You have a better solution, which is to use a VPN.  Don't address the bad solution with a detailed explanation of why it's bad.  Just use the standard, good solution -- VPN with SSL.

Comment: It matters indeed -- alternative solution aside I'm interested in any real-world practical vulnerability of a long-term open connection to bolster my own knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the client will maintain a persistent connection to server

No such thing exists.

Each connection -- no matter how long it's supposed to last -- will eventually get disconnected.  It may be seconds before the disconnect or centuries, but it will eventually get disconnected.  Nothing is "persistent" in the sense of perpetually on.

There is no such thing as a "keep-alive mechanism".  It **will** get disconnected.

"Assume the server authenticates the client upon connection".  Can't assume that.  That's the vulnerability.   Unless you have a secure socket layer (SSL) to assure that the TCP/IP traffic itself is secure.  If you're going to use SSL, why mess around with "keep-alive"?

When it gets disconnected, how does it get connected again?  And how do you trust the connection?

Scenario One: Denial of Service.

1. Bad Guys are probing your socket waiting for it to accept a connection.
2. Your "persistent" connection goes down.  (Either client crashed or you crashed or network routing infrastructure crashed.  Doesn't matter.  Socket dead.  Must reconnect.)
3. Bad Guys get your listening socket first.  They spoof their IP address and you think they're the client.  They're in -- masquerading as the client.
4. The client host attempts their connection and you reject it saying they're already connected.

Indeed, this is the **exact** reason why folks invented and use SSL.

Based on this, you can dream up a DNS-enabled scenario that will allow Bad Guys to (a) get connected and then (b) adjust a DNS entry to make them receive connections intended for you.  Now they're in the middle.  Ideally, DNS security foils this, but it depends on the client's configuration.  They could be open to DNS hacks, who knows?

The point is this.

**Don't Count On A Persistent Connection**

It doesn't exist.  Everything gets disconnected and reconnected.  That's why we have SSL.

---

> The client can simply reconnect, the server must respond to the user request with the appropriate error.

False.  The client cannot "simply" reconnect.  Anyone can connect.  Indeed, you have to assume "everyone" is trying to connect and will beat the approved client.

To be sure it's the approved client you have to exchange credentials.  Essentially implementing SSL.  Don't implement your own SSL.  Use existing SSL.

---

> would they have to break into a switch site?

Only in the movies.  In the real world, we use packet sniffers.

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified that -- I was using 'persistent' with an implicit caveat of 'within the bounds of possibility'. I will create (a) a keep-alive mechanism for the socket (empty TCP payload every 5 mins perhaps) and (b) a handling mechanism for the 'no active connection' eventuality.

The client can simply reconnect, the server must respond to the user request with the appropriate error.

I'll add some clarification as I think my question's not quite pointing in the right direction. Thanks for the responses so far :-)

Comment: Ok that provides an alternative (for which I am grateful - and your good justification of it as a better solution will strengthen the case for it), but for my own education I'd still be interested in the answer to the original question - practically is anyone /likely/ to be able to eavesdrop on Internet traffic outside a LAN environment?

Comment: @boycy: Yes.  (1) When your connection is dropped and reconnected it can be spoofed.  (2) All unencrypted data is completely visible in the TCP/IP packet stream -- every router sees all of your data in the clear.

Comment: @boycy:  The question (above) says "spoof".  Your comment says "listen".  Which is it?

Comment: By 'eavesdrop' I meant the attacker would be able to see, and hence manipulate, data passing through a network element. I guess my question is about the physical security of Internet network elements. I wanted to ignore the security of the connecting itself (because I feel comfortable with my knowledge there) and look at the security of a longterm connection compared to an on-demand connection.

Sorry, I'm not trying to be a pain here, though I think I've achieved it.

Comment: @boycy: There is **no** physical security on The Internet (in the large).  Everything is readable (and indeed actually read) by every router on the net.  I'll repeat that, since it seems to confuse you.  Everything is readable (and indeed actually read) by every router on the net.  What's your question?  Please **update** the question so people don't have to integrate a bunch of comments to figure out what you're talking about.

Comment: I am not confused about the concept that every router on the net can read the data and am somewhat offended by the patronising repetition. I do know that a router can read the packets and am not completely new to network programming. 
I'm (a) sorry that this question is frustrating you and (b) very grateful for your time. I'm obviously finding it difficult to phrase it in a way which elicits the information I'm asking for. Despite rephrasing the question in the last comment I will do so above as you request.

Comment: @boycy:  There is no such thing  as a "long term" connection.  Why do you keep trying to focus on that?

Comment: So you wouldn't define a network connection which is maintained open and reestablished if dropped longterm?

Comment: @boycy: It's "on demand".  The demand is -- theoretically -- less frequent, but there's no "persistent".  All you have is on-demand frequently (i.e., HTTP) and on-demand rarely (your "keep-alive" thing).  It's still TCP/IP and it's still on demand.

Comment: I know it's not a technical term, but I'm trying to contrast between a connection open for a short amount of time and one open for a long period of time.

Regarding the packet sniffing mechanism, where can you sniff the packets if you don't break into a switch site?

Comment: @boycy: There's no distinction between short and long duration.  They're both "on-demand" with the exact same vulnerabilities.  The Same.  I would sniff packets through my Cable TV provider because I'm too cheap to actually contract with a Telco for a proper T1 or DS1 connection.

Comment: So you're saying that if you have a cable connection then the immediate network element outside your house is a hub not a switch?

Comment: And thanks, I guess "The Same" answers my question, though I feel far more stupid than when I asked it..

Comment: And as far as the distinction goes, I know the protocol doesn't give two hoots about it, but let me explain why I thought it might be important by way of analogy.
Compare the difference in home security between someone who only unlocks their door when they want to go through it, and someone who leaves their door unlocked all the time. Not exactly a watertight analogy but it may help you understand why I asked the question

Comment: "is a hub not a switch" too subtle a distinction for me.  Download `satan` or other Black-Hat network analysis/hacking software.  The Internet itself is very wide open.  The individual sites (behind firewalls) are not so open.  But sniffing unencrypted traffic is done by kids with open source software.  They're called "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_kiddie" and the net's full of 'em.

Comment: @boycy: "Not exactly a watertight analogy".  Not even close.  The analogy is someone who opens their door frequently vs. rarely.  Either way, **the door must be opened**.  You can try to do it less often, but that does not change the essential vulnerability.  It only changes the frequency.

Comment: Not sure I understand; the distinction is important surely? If you connect out to a hub, you will receive packets not destined to/from your public IP. If it's a switch, then you will only receive packets to/from your IP. SATAN seems to be a port scanner with greatly extended functionality, which would allow you to scan someone, but not to receive packets from a switch which aren't destined for your network.
No, my original analogy was actually closer to what I was asking than yours. But thanks.

Comment: @boycy: "the distinction is important".  Not really. 
The script kiddies can't all be buying proper routers from telcos.  (I suppose they **all** could be buying routers, but I doubt it.)  This leads me to conclude that at least one cable provider allows script kiddies an unreasonable level of access.  Additionally, there are any number of tunneling protocols as well as unsecured routers.  The "hub/switch" business doesn't have any **practical** significance, since hacking goes on irrespective of that distinction.

Comment: `Each connection -- no matter how long it's supposed to last -- will eventually get disconnected. It may be seconds before the disconnect or centuries, but it will eventually get disconnected. Nothing is "persistent" in the sense of perpetually on.` What nonsense. "Persistent" is not the same as "permanent" and this is precisely why.

Comment: `There is no such thing as a "keep-alive mechanism". It will get disconnected.` Similarly, a life support machine is still a life support machine even if you don't keep it plugged in for infinity years.